# ASP.NET C# Services using IRepository and each other

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have my `IRepository` interface which is bound using `Ninject` and `InRequestScope`.

The Repository Binding is:

```
kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<DefaultRepository>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("dbContext", dbContext => kernel.Get<DefaultContext>());
```

If I have a service `IAccountService` which is bound in the same way.

The concrete implementation:

```
public class AccountService : IAccountService
{
    IRepository _repository;

    public AccountService(IRepository repository) { _repository = repository; }
}
```

If I now create another service `IBlogService` which is bound in the same way.

The concrete implementation:

```
public class BlogService : IBlogService
{
    IRepository _repository;
    IAccountService _accountService;

    public AccountService(IRepository repository, IAccountService accountService) 
    {
        _repository = repository; 
        _accountService = accountService;
    }
}
```

Both these services are asking for `IRepository` are they getting the same instance or are they requesting two completely different isolated `DbContext`s?

It does "work" but is there an obvious downfall to this method?

Comment: Stop using generic repositories.

Comment: I'm serious, if you're using a generic repository, you're doing it wrong. Stop it. Stop creating a mess.

Comment: Okay, I don't doubt that you are, but you haven't really expanded on why, how you should do it, any resources I should look at. The trade offs to using generic or writing tonnes more code for the many many entities I will have

Comment: Here's a few, http://www.philliphaydon.com/2014/01/if-youre-going-to-use-repositories-dont-have-generic-or-base-repositories/ there's many more on google.

Comment: I see the points and can agree with them, but like many people who have commented on the article, its down to professional judgement. I would like to point out that the crux of this problem isn't based on Generic Repositories, more of the underlying `DbContext`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58160/discussion-between-no1-melman-and-phill).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use `.InRequestScope()` all services are getting the same instance of `DefaultRepository` during your request. So when a new request comes in, an new instance of your `DefaultRepository` is created.

Also if your `IRepository` interface implements `IDisposable`, Ninject will dispose it when needed.

I don't think there is any downfall, since in web applications, the lifecycle of your `DbContext` should be per request (unless you have very good reasons not to follow this approach).

**EDIT**

You can also implement a transaction per request pattern, so you can avoid inconsistency if saving in one repository succeeds, but saving in another repository fails. This way you can rollback all the changes if anything goes wrong during your request.

Not saying you should implement this, just wanted to let you know it's possible. This is a very basic example, you should do some extra checks on when you want to create a transaction (for example only on http POSTS), and maybe you want to delegate this to a seperate class so your Global.asax will not be cluttered with all this resposiblilites. Another thing to mention is that this will only work if you have your DbContext injected with .InRequestScope(), so the same context is used through your request.

It works like this:

In your Global.asax Application_BeginRequest() method, you should initialize your transaction like this:

```
  var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
  _httpContext.Items["_Transaction"] = transaction;
```

In your Global.asax Application_Error() method, you can set an error flag like this

```
_httpContext.Items["_Error"] = true;
```

Finally in your Global.asax Application_EndRequest() you can commit everything if there are no errors, or else rollback:

```
  var transaction = (DbContextTransaction)_httpContext.Items["_Transaction"];

  if (_httpContext.Items["_Error"] != null)
        transaction.Rollback();
  else
        transaction.Commit();
```

Comment: Should I implement `IDisposable`?

Comment: @No1_Melman I think it's better to implement IDisposable in your repository, and in the IDispose method of your repository, call the Dispose method on your DbContext so all resources will be cleaned up like the underlying sql connection etc. You can also choose to put the DbContext in your IoC container have it injected in your repositories. That way you let Ninject manage it's lifecylce

Comment: @No1_MelmanOne other thing to mention is that it's also possible to have a "Transaction per Request". Right now you can call SaveChanges in different repo's, resulting in different transactions. I'll edit my post in a few minutes to show you...

Comment: That is a very interesting concept, I will look to try and implement that in another project. Would this work well with `RowVersion`?